# Advancement on payment

Tags: company-policy

I'm a small business owner for commercial property renovations. I currently have a contract with a general construction company which was scheduled to start April 1. Due to delays on filing by the G.C. I've had to wait for another 2 months to begin construction. 
  My question is, would it be acceptable to ask for a small amount of the agreement scheduled 1st payment to help cover my rent. This advancement is a result of the postponement of the project in which I was relying on as income.

Comment: What does the current contract say? If there is a line along the theme of "payment upon completion" things get a lot more difficult.

Comment: Structure your future contacts with a staggered payment profile ie 20% on acceptance, 30% at the "halfway point", 50% on completion with a clause about late starts.

Comment: Voting to close; this is a question about a business decision.

Comment: You can ask, but if an upfront payment isn't in your contract then don't be surprised if you don't get anything. In the future, you should include a payment schedule in your contract that includes an upfront payment.

Comment: This is primarily a business and legal decision, not a workplace query. Other than that, @joeqwerty pretty much nails it: you can ask, but you're unlikely to get anything before you've completed any work.

Answer (score 4):

> would it be acceptable to ask for a small amount of the agreement
>   scheduled 1st payment to help cover my rent.

You can ask for anything.

But if it isn't in the contract, don't be surprised if the answer is "No".

Just explain that the delay put you in a difficult spot, and hope for the best.